# Integrating Mailgun with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, email, http, ionic-framework, mailgun

I want to send email without using email composer, so I followed tutorial from https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/05/send-emails-ionic-2-mobile-app-via-rackspace-mailgun-api/ to use Mailgun API. Since Http from "@angular/http" has been deprecated, the code from tutorial is not working anymore. Here is what I have so far:

I replaced

```
import {Http, Request, RequestMethod} from "@angular/http";
```

with

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
```

and send method is

```
send() {
    this.http.post(this.mailgunUrl + "/messages",
    body: "from=test@example.com&to=" + "recipient@example.com" + "&subject=" + "test subject" + "&text=" + "test message sent", 
    {
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.mailgunApiKey}
    }).subscribe(success => {
        console.log("SUCCESS -> " + JSON.stringify(success));
    }, error => {
        console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

http: HttpClient is added to the parameter for the constructor. I also added

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

to app.motule.ts file.
When I run, I get this error:

```
POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomainthaticopiedfrommailgunwebsite.mailgun.org/messages 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)

ERROR -> {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"statusText":"UNAUTHORIZED","url":"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomainthaticopiedfrommailgunwebsite.mailgun.org/messages","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomainthaticopiedfrommailgunwebsite.mailgun.org/messages: 401 UNAUTHORIZED","error":"Forbidden"}
```

I also added CORS Chrome extension. What is the correct way to send email using Mailgun API on Ionic?

Comment: Is this issue resolved. If so please share the correct answer, I am also facing similar issue. thx

Comment: @metalhead101 yes. the answer below solved my issue. I also had to add "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"' to the header as stated on the comment to the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `this.mailgunApiKey`, what's its value? If you are using your Mailgun API key it's wrong. You should use:

`"Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")`

Where username is 'api' and password is your API Key.

Comment: `this.mailgunApiKey` is `window.btoa("key-someKeyNumber")`.
So instead of putting just Mailgun API key, do I need to have Mailgun URL that goes like `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxSomeNumbersAndLetters.mailgun.org`?

Comment: The URL looks right, just change the params of the btoa function, instead of the string "key-someKeyNumber" put "api:key-someKeyNumber", where key-someKeyNumber is the api key you find in your profile for the app in Mailgun. (api is just that, the string 'api')

Comment: I also had to add '"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"' to the header, but putting string 'api' in front worked! Thank you so much